# Debug.Print vs. Debug.WriteLine

Tags: c#, debugging

What's the difference between `Debug.Print` and `Debug.WriteLine`?  The summary of both in MSDN is the same:

> Writes a message followed by a line terminator to the trace listeners in the Listeners collection.

`Debug.WriteLine` has more overloads.  I can't see a reason why `Debug.Print` would be used instead of `Debug.WriteLine`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

They both do the same thing, but its interesting that `Debug.Print` will only take a string, while `Debug.WriteLine` will accept an object which ends up calling the object's `ToString` method.

With Reflector:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public static void Print(string message){
    TraceInternal.WriteLine(message);
}

[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public static void WriteLine(string message){
    TraceInternal.WriteLine(message);
}

[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public static void WriteLine(object value)
{
    TraceInternal.WriteLine(value);
}
```

I'd be willing to bet that `Debug.Print` was a hold over from Visual Basic.

**Edit:** From a tutorial on [Tracing VB.NET Windows Application](http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/vb.net-2005/vb.net-2005-tracing-a-windows-application.html):

> In Visual Basic.NET 2005, the
>   Debug.Write, Debug.WriteIf,
>   Debug.WriteLine, and Debug.WriteLineIf
>   methods have been replaced with the
>   Debug.Print method that was available
>   in earlier versions of Visual Basic.

Sure sounds like `Debug.Print` was a hold over from pre-`C#` days.

Answer (score 8):

`Debug.Print` and `Debug.WriteLine` each offers an overload that takes a single string parameter. Internally, those single-parameter methods work in the same way and call this method:

```
TraceInternal.WriteLine(message);
```

The difference between the two methods is that `Debug.Print` offers an overload with two arguments: [`Debug.Print(String, Object[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/867tyd42%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). That overload of `Print` can display a *formatted string*. There is no overload of `Debug.WriteLine` that offers that functionality, but you can of course use:

```
Debug.WriteLine(string.Format())
```

`WriteLine` was introduced in .NET Framework 1.1 and `Print` in Framework 2.0. In my opinion, Microsoft should have stayed with `WriteLine` as the name of the method and added a `WriteLine(String, Object[])` overload, instead of adding the `Print` method.

Comment: Actually, `WriteLine` does offer the overload [`WriteLine(String, Object[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190153%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which can write a formatted string. However, you have to be careful that you don't inadvertently invoke the [`WriteLine(String, String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w33ay0x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22819330/1497596) for how to invoke the overload of `WriteLine` that you intend.

Answer (score 2):

They didn't want to risk breaking a .NET language that considers both overloads ambiguous.  They very nearly are, WriteLine("foo") could match WriteLine(string) and WriteLine(string, params object[]).  C# has a rule for it but that's specific to that language.

Answer (score 1):

From the prototypes:

```
public static void Print(string message);
public static void Print(string format, params object[] args);

public static void WriteLine(object value);
public static void WriteLine(string message);
```

It looks like Print can do formatted strings and WriteLine can dump objects.

Comment: Per my comment on another answer, `WriteLine` can also do [formatted strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411999/debug-print-vs-debug-writeline#comment52339367_5412083).