# Why does Debug.WriteLine incorrectly format strings?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following `Debug.WriteLine`:

```
Debug.WriteLine("Metadata Version: {0}", version); // update: version is a string
```

The output is:

> 2.0: Metadata Version: {0}

Why is the string formatted this way?

I didn't see anything in MSDN documentation that identifies reasoning behind this format. I have to do the following to get a correctly formatted output:

```
Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Metadata Version: {0}", version));
```

Comment: What is the type of version ?

Comment: @Habib To replicate this behavior it would need to be a `string`.

Comment: @Servy, yes thats what I thought, it is using the other overload

Comment: Updated question to clarify `version` is a `string`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since `version` is a `string`, you're hitting [the overload of `WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1w33ay0x) that accepts a category as its second parameter.

While there are any number of hacks to get around this behavior (I'll include a few below, for fun) I would personally prefer your solution as the preferable way of clearly ensuring that the string is treated as a format string.

Some other hacky workarounds:

```
Debug.WriteLine("Metadata Version: {0}", version, "");
Debug.WriteLine("Metadata Version: {0}", (object)version);
Debug.WriteLine("Metadata Version: {0}", new[] { version });
Debug.WriteLine("Metadata Version: {0}", version, null);
```

Comment: While the workaroud is easy this is a bad class' desginer, IMHO.

Comment: For fun and glory.

Answer (score 16):

Since your `version` is string, it is using [Debug.WriteLine Method (String, String) overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/a1z6t089).

You can do couple of things to get the right result:

```
Debug.WriteLine("Metadata Version: {0}",(object) version);
```

Or you can use [`Debug.Print`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/867tyd42)

```
Debug.Print("Metadata Version: {0}", version);
```

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively you could use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated). Just put a `$` sign in front of the string and specify the variable in braces `{variableName}`.

```
Debug.WriteLine($"Metadata Version: {version}");
```

Comment: This feature is available starting with C# 6.

Comment: Unavailable at the time the accepted answer was made, but probably the best solution now.

Comment: Ah, I'm late to the game I suppose.... 

Answer (score 1):

It is resolving your method call to [this overload of Debug.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1w33ay0x), which takes a message string as its first parameter and a category string as the second parameter.

If you cast the version parameter to System.Object, it will resolve to [the desired overload of Debug.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc190153), which takes a format string as its first parameter and one or more objects as subsequent parameters.

```
Debug.WriteLine("Metadata Version: {0}", (object)version);
```

Comment: It's actually going to go to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1w33ay0x) overload, not the one you specified, although those two will do the same thing here.  This overload is "better" given the overload resolution's betterness algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Using [*named arguments*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments) for the format string helps the compiler select the correct WriteLine overload.

```
Debug.WriteLine(format: "Metadata Version: {0}", version);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or write your own wrapper

```
    protected static void DebugOutput(string format, params object[] args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(format, args);
    }
```