# Easy C# question about the Debug.Writeline() with parameters

Tags: c#

While debugging my application, I came across a behavior I'm puzzled by.  I have the following

```
foreach (var customer in _dbContext.Customer)
{
  Debug.WriteLine("Customer Name: {0}", customer.Name);  // The output was not what I expected.
...
}
```

### Actual Output

Peter:Customer Name: {0}

However, if I rewrite the statement to this.

```
foreach (var customer in _dbContext.Customer)
{
  Debug.WriteLine("Customer Name: " + customer.Name);  
...
}
```

### Actual Output

Customer Name: Peter

I added the following the code to the same file to see why my original code wasn't working.

```
string first = "Peter";
string last = "Piper";
string what = "pick";
Debug.WriteLine("1 {0} 2 {1}, 3 {0} 4 {1}, 5 {2}.", first, last, what);
```

### Actual Output

1 Peter 2 Piper, 3 Peter 4 Piper, 5 pick.

I am not sure why `Debug.WriteLine("Customer Name: {0}", customer.Name);` would output this `CusPeter:Customer Name: {0}`

Many Thanks

Comment: Different overload: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_Debug_WriteLine_System_String_System_String_ - try `Debug.WriteLine("Customer Name: {0}", (object)customer.Name)` instead

Comment: Overload resolution rules are obscure and I wouldn't recommend memorizing them but when your types perfectly match a given signature you shouldn't be surprised that it's the one chosen.

Comment: Is there any aversion to using just straight interpolation? $"Customer Name: {customer.Name}";?

Comment: Thank you all.  All those suggestions worked.  I'm not sure why casting (object) worked though. '.Name' is already.  Originally, I even tried Name.ToString and it still didn't output correctly.

Comment: it didn't work because using overload with two strings, the second one is the category not the value. Also the first one in such scenario is not the format but the complete message. If you want to use formatting you need to pass an array as the second one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Debug.WriteLine incorrectly format strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22819117/why-does-debug-writeline-incorrectly-format-strings)

Comment: `Debug.WriteLine` is, bizarrely, **not** `Console.WriteLine` but writing to the debug console rather than standard out. It would be nice if it were, but it isn't, so expecting that it is will lead to confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem happens because of the overload of the method. When you pass a `string` as a second parameter, it maps to the following method:

[image]

As you can see, this overload is not expecting "arguments", as you would when you want to replace them in a string, but rather is waiting for a "category" of the de Debug information.

The code casting your string to object works because of the following overload:

[image]

As you can see, when you cast your string to "object", it maps to another overload of the `WriteLine` method, which is actually expecting values to be formatted into a string. I believe this answers your doubt about why it works when casting to object.

Answer (score 1):

A working alternative is using [$ string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

Yielding this

`Debug.Writline($"CustomerName {customer.Name});`

I accidently answered this in comments but found out the the actual reason is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22819117/why-does-debug-writeline-incorrectly-format-strings) and that we're hitting the wrong overload, and not the one for interpolation.